# Select with COALESCE built list in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

I have a query that needs to return a set of fields, along with a list of data returned as a single character-separated string.

Say I have 2 tables

**tblPeople**

```
NamePK    Name
-----------------
1         Fred
2         Tom
```

**tblNotes**

```
NameFK    Note
------------------------
1         Likes to talk
1         Types fast
2         Joined the internet
```

Then my answer would look like this (if I separated with a '+')

```
NamePK    Name    Notes
-------------------------------------------
1         Fred    Likes to talk+Types fast
2         Tom     Joined the internet
```

I believe I have to use the COALESCE function. I have used it in the past to create comma-delimited values, but I am unsure on how to do this in a select. I'm using MSSQL.

Any ideas or approaches?

suggestions:
[Sql COALESCE entire rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408269/sql-coalesce-entire-rows)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  It's a SQL Anti-Pattern...

Comment: What version of SQL Server?. Anyway, this group concatenation thing has been asked many, many times before. I recommend you to do a search on SO with the tags `sql-server` and `group-concat`

Comment: COALESCE is for dealing with nulls, not pivoting data.

Comment: The people I work for are crazy. The end result sort of makes sense, but I understand that this is not common SQL practice. If you can think of a better way to format this, please suggest.

Comment: @NWest - More than pivoting data is concatenating data

Comment: @Lamak Once it's pivoted, the concatenating is easy ;-)

Comment: [Here's a stackoverflow question that answers what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368942/grouped-string-aggregation-listagg-for-sql-server)

Comment: I know i can concat using COALESCE. [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1521/the-many-uses-of-coalesce-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @gunr2171 the `COALESCE` function does *not* concatenate. It simply returns the first argument to the function that is `NOT NULL`.  You concatenate columns using the `+` operator in SQL Server.

Comment: @gunr2171 - Your link shows coalesce being used to deal with nulls to allow a concatentation. It does not show coleasce being use to do the concatenation. It especially has nothing to do with concatention over multiple rows.  *[I strongly suggest looking at the answsers linked to above, they show methods for achieving what you have asked for.]*

Comment: @nwest - Except that in the OPs case you need to pivot to an unknown number of columns.  Which isn't so easy.

Comment: What I said - the pivot's the hard part :)

Comment: @Dems, There is only one column I need to pivot. And thanks to everyone's suggestions so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` to do the concatenation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139472/concatenate-grouped-rows) for an example. There are improvements that can be made, such as eliminating extra delimiters, if you search around for other questions involving `STUFF`.

```
SELECT p.NamePK, p.Name,
 STUFF((
        select '+' + n.Note
        from tblNote n
        where n.NameFK = p.NamePK
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
FROM tblPeople p
```